# SSL Cert for Tomcat on EC2 with ELB

Tags: ssl, tomcat, amazon-ec2, certificate, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a Tomcat server on EC2, with an application loadbalancer, and needs to be provided TLS encryption. The Tomcat caters to an application that opens up on my custom domain, say `www.mydomain.com/somebusiness`.
As such I have installed an AWS provided certificate on the ELB, but the traffic from port 443 to the Tomcat server cannot served by the AWS certificate. Which means I need another certificate separately for Tomcat. I tried using a self generated cert but kept getting
"Your connection is not private, attackers might be trying to steal your information from ...".
Which made me go for a CA signed certificate, hoping it would solve the problem.
The real problem started here for me. My certificate is issued for `www.mydomain.com` and I installed the certificate on the load balancer, which still has a DNS name `https://blappity.amazon.aws.com`. Technically my certificate now rejects this because of the domain name mismatch.
Bottom line, I cannot provide a custom DNS name for my load balancer, for unavoidable reasons, which eliminates the Route 53 option for me.
What would be the best way forward for me to align the custom domain with the ELB at this point?

Answer (score 1):

This is typically managed with [SSL Offloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS_termination_proxy).

Long story short: you handle SSL on your ALB, which is exposed to the internet, and it communicates via HTTP (unsecured) with your EC2 instance. 
This instance is not exposed to the internet but can communicate only with your ALB through specific Security Group rules.
In this way, you can point the DNS of your domain to the ALB's EIP (or, if you're using Route53, to the ALB Alias).

Some more details and a step-by-step guide:

- Create your ALB.
- Create your EC2 instance and expose your application via HTTP, e.g., on port 80. Don't assign it a public IP, and ensure (through Security Groups) that it can communicate only with the ALB.
- Create a Target Group where you'll add the EC2 instance. Remember to set up a health check path (a simple endpoint that can be accessed via GET and always returns a 200 status code). [Create a Target Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-target-group.html)
- Create (or import) an SSL certificate for your domain, and install it in your ALB's SNI. [Request a Public Certificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request-public.html)
- Install the certificate on the ALB and create a listener rule that redirects HTTPS traffic (e.g., on port 443), validated with your certificate, to the previously created Target Group. [Create an HTTPS Listener](https://Create%20an%20HTTPS%20listener%20for%20your%20Application%20Load%20Balancer%20-%20Elastic%20Load%20Balancing)
- Optionally, but recommended, create another listener rule to redirect HTTP traffic (on port 80) to the HTTPS port (and thus to the HTTPS listener). [Redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb)
- Add a record to your DNS to redirect requests for your custom domain to the ALB.

Comment: Thanks Filippo. I have pretty much done (before asking this question here, that is) everything except the point you have mentioned "optionally". Including the DNS record to redirect requests to the custom domain to the ALB. Will evaluate the missing point and go from there

Comment: Adding the listener rule to redirect HTTP port 80 to the HTTPS port didn't help. Probably because my load balancer is already on SSL and has a HTTPS endpoint.